# How is Angular2 documentation generated?

Tags: angular, build

The [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/), are darn pretty. Is it generated from source code, or hand-maintained?

There is a [docs folder](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/%40angular/docs) but I can't seem to see where these appear on the documentation web site. There are definitely docs [embedded in the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/src/http.ts#L49).

If there is doc generation in the current build, it seems a bit obfuscated. I would love to learn the backstory on how this is accomplished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Angular 2](https://angular.io/) is maintained at a different [github repository](https://github.com/angular/angular.io).

you may look into the source code at this [repository](https://github.com/angular/angular.io).

Source code for Typescript version of documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/tree/master/public/docs/ts/latest)